# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 internet problem - can't connect to some sites

Tags: gnome, internet, 17.04

After installing Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 I can't load about half of the pages I try to access with any internet browser. For example, Google is loading but YouTube or Facebook shows a 104 error.
In settings I can't connect to my Google account.

I tried Firefox, Chrome and other browsers and find that its not a browser problem; they all show the same.

I tried to run the OS from live USB and have the same problem... any ideas?

Comment: Good day for all, today I was tried Kubuntu 17.04 live boot and find the same problem. Chromium shows 'DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN'.

Comment: P.S. I'm dual boot with Windows 10. Is it posible that Windows change something in BIOS and it cast this problem? little bit later I would try to install older version on ubuntu (maybe 16.04) to find range of problem

Comment: Since you dual boot with Windows, does that same problem occur there as well? Is it the same sites? Firefox, Chrome, and IE?

Comment: A 104 error? There's no such HTTP status code. Do you mean [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#404)? What's the output of `host www.youtube.com`, `host www.youtube.com 8.8.8.8` and `LS_MESSAGES=POSIX wget -SO /dev/null --progress=dot https://www.youtube.com/`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 - some sites were working, others - Facebook, YouTube - not.

I set DNS in Ip4 settings to 8.8.8.8, DHCP left still as automatic. Now sites are working, also some apps like Steam are functioning correctly.

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about your setup and network configuration, a "fix" like this suggests that something in the upgrade messed up how the computer gets it's configuration data from the DHCP server. Further testing to confirm or deny that as the cause is needed. If that _is_ the root of the problem, then filing a bug report with Ubuntu would be a good idea.