# How to set up a Wi-Fi hot-spot on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: hot-spot, 17.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04. In Ubuntu 16.10, I could setup a WiFi hot-spot to give Internet access to my Android phone using the trick mentioned in this article [Share internet with Android Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/share-internet-with-android-ubuntu-1404/). I can connect to WiFi now using the fix mentioned in answer to this question: [Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04).

But when I click on "Connect to Hidden WiFi Network" and choose to start the hot-spot setup, I see this notification and it doesn't start.

[image: Wireless Disconnected]

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 16.10/17.04 issue with creating hot-spot using Network Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906069/ubuntu-gnome-16-10-17-04-issue-with-creating-hot-spot-using-network-manager)

Answer (score 5):

I hope this article can help with your problem.

[How to Overcome Ubuntu 17.04 Failed to Make Wifi Hotspot](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abuhamzah.web.id%2F2017%2F04%2Fcara-mengatasi-ubuntu-1704-gagal-bikin.html&edit-text=&act=url)

1. If Hotspot is on then turn it off first. Go to **System Settings > Network**

   Turn off Hotspot by clicking <kbd>ON</kbd> so it becomes <kbd>OFF</kbd>

   Click <kbd>Stop Hotspot</kbd>
2. Click **All Settings > Software and Updates**

   Make sure the settings shown are checked.

   [image]
3. Click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button and let Ubuntu 17.04 update after entering the password. Wait for it to finish. Click <kbd>Reload</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start the Terminal application.
5. Type the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install hostapd dnsmasq
   ```
6. Go back to the **Network** window and click <kbd>Use as Hotspot</kbd> then click <kbd>Turn On</kbd>.

   Hotspot is ON with the name HP-EliteBook-2760p (on my computer)
7. In order for Android devices to be able to connect to this Hotspot, there is still one more step, namely:

   Click **Edit Connections**

   Select **Hotspot** then click **Edit**

   Change **Mode** to **Hotspot (provided Ad-hoc)**

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

   Click **Enable Wi-Fi** to disable your Wi-Fi

   Click again **Enable Wi-Fi** to enable Wi-Fi

And…. Alhamdulillah ... now Hotspot on Ubuntu 17.04 can function normally. Android devices can also connect.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

OK. To fix the problem, just install hostapd and dnsmasq from repository.

Type on terminal:

Sudo apt install hostapd dnsmasq