# Ubuntu GNOME 16.10/17.04 issue with creating hot-spot using Network Manager

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, android, hot-spot

I've experienced the following problem on Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 and 17.04.

Using Gnome-Network-Manager (I don't want to use other tools) I have issues when I create a wifi hot-spot to allow my Android device to access wired Internet.  Sometimes (usually after a fresh boot) the wifi hot-spot works.  But after a short while (maybe 10 to 30 minutes), my Android system will disconnect.  When I reconnect Android will say something like "Connected, no Internet", but the Internet is available.

This is not a problem with just one Android system or device, I have tested with various versions of Android (Samsung and CynagenMod) and a Mac Book.  All with similar issues.

From the Android side it appears that the network signal strengths fluctuates significantly over time.

I have tried various network cards, the internal network card ([Intel AC 7260](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/75439/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260)) and a couple of USB network cards.  All exhibit similar behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this article can help with your problem.

[How to Overcome Ubuntu 17.04 Failed to Make Wifi Hotspot](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abuhamzah.web.id%2F2017%2F04%2Fcara-mengatasi-ubuntu-1704-gagal-bikin.html&edit-text=&act=url)

1. If Hotspot is on then turn it off first. Go to **System Settings > Network**

   Turn off Hotspot by clicking <kbd>ON</kbd> so it becomes <kbd>OFF</kbd>

   Click <kbd>Stop Hotspot</kbd>
2. Click **All Settings > Software and Updates**

   Make sure the settings shown are checked.

   [image]
3. Click the <kbd>Close</kbd> button and let Ubuntu 17.04 update after entering the password. Wait for it to finish. Click <kbd>Reload</kbd>.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to start the Terminal application.
5. Type the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install hostapd dnsmasq
   ```
6. Go back to the **Network** window and click <kbd>Use as Hotspot</kbd> then click <kbd>Turn On</kbd>.

   Hotspot is ON with the name HP-EliteBook-2760p (on my computer)
7. In order for Android devices to be able to connect to this Hotspot, there is still one more step, namely:

   Click **Edit Connections**

   Select **Hotspot** then click **Edit**

   Change **Mode** to **Hotspot (provided Ad-hoc)**

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>

   Click **Enable Wi-Fi** to disable your Wi-Fi

   Click again **Enable Wi-Fi** to enable Wi-Fi

And…. Alhamdulillah ... now Hotspot on Ubuntu 17.04 can function normally. Android devices can also connect.