# Create hotspot from LAN cable in ubuntu 17.04 gnome using terminal

Tags: networking, gnome, network-manager, 17.04, hot-spot

I have been searching this but could not find a proper solution. Creating it directly from Network Manager GUI doesn't work. It gives the following error:

```
Activation of network connection failed.
```

If anybody knows how to do it using terminal in Ubuntu 17.04 gnome can please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to search for "bridge" connection to let a computer connected to the internet (via cable or wifi) share its connection via wifi.  There's a process, but it's not something you can just install or turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a couple of packages.  From the command line type:

```
sudo apt install hostapd dnsmasq
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906069/ubuntu-gnome-16-10-17-04-issue-with-creating-hot-spot-using-network-manager?rq=1) for full details.