# Nameserver changes to 127.0.1.1 while connecting to wifi in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, dns, 17.04

I have upgraded the ubuntu from 16.10 to 17.04 and I am able to connect to wifi but not able to browse any website as DNS resolver not working.

I have searched the exiting issues and think that it was same issue as mention in [Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04)

But the above solution is not working so as temporary fix I have used the below manual steps :

open `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`

enter the following in `resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Please suggest any permanent fix because every time I will connect to wifi I have to perform this step manually.

Comment: What is the output of these commands: `nmcli device`, `nmcli connection`. if you get any output add them tho your question.