# no internet browsing from ubuntu MATE 17.04

Tags: networking, internet, dns, 17.04

After upgrading to 17.04 I can't use either Firefox or Chromium to browse the internet. with a wi-fi ADSL NETGEAR modem-router (DGN2000 Wireless N 300), but I do with a Sitecom ADSL modem-router in a different location. 1) My laptop is connected to the modem-router. 2) I can connect by ssh to remote systems BY USING NUMERIC IPs. So I guess the problem is with the NAME SERVERS. After looking around I FOUND A WORKAROUND here: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2347827.html by tokyobadger. I edited the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf as suggested and now I can use my browsers.
I want to signal the problem though.

Comment: I think I read about that somewhere else, some new "feature" that often ends up crippling the internet. Anyway, if you want to edit your question , you can answer it yourself too, with detailed info like exactly what's causing the problem and how to fix it

Comment: Is this working `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: @Tarunkant: I tried, but simply restarting the network manager does not help.

Comment: I verified that this is **NOT** the same problem as the "randomization of MAC address" I have reading  about, here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04 and here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019

Comment: The wokaround solution I cited above (from https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2347827.html) is the following: edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
uncomment DNS and set to 8.8.8.8
uncomment DNSSEC and set the flag to =off