# Ubuntu 17.04: Can't connect to wifi after update from 16.10

Tags: networking, upgrade, 17.04

Today I have updated my system from 16.10 to 17.04. While updating my internet fluctuated for some time and after doing restart it completely stopped working.

I tried to figure out and found [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04)
but it is not working for me.

Please provide me with some solutions

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something restarts dnsmasq. I followed
https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me, assuming the solution you linked didn't work:
Open a terminal:
Use this command:

```
sudo killall dnsmasq
```

I hope this works for you like it did for me!