# No Internet connection under 17.04

Tags: networking, internet, 17.04

The Ubuntu 17.04 distribution is not connecting to Internet, not in a live USB session, nor after the install. I've got a Dell Inspiron 24-7459. This is a major issue as I cannot update or download anything. Without the possibility of connecting to the Internet I'm completely stuck.

I've followed the instructions on this thread and nothing changes:

[Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04)

In my case it's not a question of WIFI only. The Internet is not working even under the wired connection.

Comment: so [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/665251) answer didn't work for you? have you tried to kill Network manager? or a reboot?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Sumeet. Before my post I already tried with no success the solutions of  the link you've send me. I've killed many times the Network manager and rebooted the systems. All the things I try give no result for the moment.

Comment: Sorry David, I should have not posted anything as I don't want to disturb or make anger anyone. It's very difficult for me to suit your requirements, as my computer has no connection and I'm trying to do want I can with another one. I don't understand fully what to do. Everybody here has lots more knowledge than me. I'm not even a English speaker. It's complicated. I just wanted to install Ubuntu. Give me a bit of time to read, understand and try to post the things the way you say. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

Go to System settings/Network/Wired/Options and then choose the enp4s0 option. It worked for me.

Comment: How does that solve Wi-Fi issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the case where I could connect to WiFi but couldn't access webpages due to DNS-related errors. 
This resolved it for me:

[Ubuntu 17.04 systemd-resolved DNS lookups randomly fail](https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail/1200745#1200745)

> Ubuntu 17.04 can not resolve DNS servers with DNSSEC support as of 2017-04-18. Disable DNSSEC with this daemon:
>
> > sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
> >     printf "[Resolve]\nDNSSEC=no\n" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/no-dnssec.conf
>
> Optionally reconfigure resolvconf if you messed with it (say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?"):
>
> > sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
>
> Restart systemd-resolved:
>
> > sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
>
> Your DNS should start working. You can check by trying systemd-resolve www.google.com and seeing a response.