# Ubuntu 17.04 does not connect to internet

Tags: networking, 17.04

After a fresh install of 17.04 on LG latop, PC connects to Wifi correctly but can not access to the internet.

1. I tried 2 different Wifi 's
2. PC connects correctly to NAS on network
3. PC connects to Router's web page.
4. Update: Problems persists using Ethernet ( Wifi is Off )

What can it be ?

PC is LG Laptop 2 core Dou, 2GB of ram, 80GB HD ( OLD but working properly )

Comment: Are there any problems with DNS? Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and also: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i dns`

Comment: @chili555 , ping is OK , syslog - " DNSSEC validation failed for question..... : failed auxiliry " what does it mean ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue, a failure of DNSSEC, is the subject of several bug reports; for instance: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1682499 and this: https://superuser.com/questions/1153203/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-resolved-dns-lookups-randomly-fail/1200745#1200745

I recommend that you undertake the fix in the second link:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
printf "[Resolve]\nDNSSEC=no\n" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/no-dnssec.conf
```

Reconfigure resolvconf if needed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?" and reboot.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: resolved.conf is not installed`

Comment: @Trix Please start your own new question.

Answer (score 3):

Go to network settings.

In wireless settings, you'd find an IPv6 tab.

Put it on **Ignore**

Comment: I did and it is ok!!!

Comment: something is not working again IPv6 is ignored

Comment: Yea, there's some bug in 17.04 Please follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04)