# Ubuntu 17.04 can not connect to one specific WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04, intel-wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad. I can connect to most Wifi networks except for one particular from a Netgear router. I tried the fix mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904844/cant-connect-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-17-04) but it did not help.

When I try to connect to said WiFi with my phone, it works...

Print from sudo lshw -class network:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: bb
       serial: 48:51:b7:a7:f5:e4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=17.459231.0 ip=192.168.0.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
```

Comment: If you can connect to all but one then the linked answer isn't applicable. First of all, you need to check that router's wireless encryption settings and make sure it's WPA2-AES only and, quoting from @chili555, *not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP*.

Comment: Encryption is WPA2-AES, that is not the problem. The router btw is a NetGear ProSafe 802.11 G, if that helps...

Comment: Indeed it helps. I suspect that router is too old. Usually I would suggest looking for firmware updates but not sure you'll find any.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelBay i forgot to answer. You were correct, I use another router now and everything works fine.