# WiFi not connecting after upgrading to 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04

I updated my Lubuntu 16.04 to 17.04 and it is now not connecting to my WiFi. It is detecting the signal, but doesn't want to connect. I deleted the connection and then tried to reconnect to the network but it has not helped.

Any ideas?

See below for info:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 02
       serial: 00:26:55:46:a4:53
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.4-3 ip=192.168.0.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f0500000-f051ffff memory:f0525000-f0525fff ioport:1100(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx74da388862b7
       serial: be:1b:f1:30:ab:b5
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.10.0-19-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

and this:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

The Wireless Info Script result can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24395115/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @DavidFoerster. I ran the script and edited the question to the result.

Comment: Sorry to tell you, yesterday I faced the same problem. Couldn't find a solution I installed back my 16.04.  There are 3 reported solution you could find. But none of them worked for me. 1)DNS 2)MAC ID 3)Download and install the driver separate. Just search it.

Comment: This worked for me after installing Ubuntu 17.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing

Comment: For some reason the `rfkill` command is unavailable on your system. Could you please reinstall it (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall rfkill`) and [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo rfkill list`? If you can't get internet via Ethernet and don't know how to install packages without an internet connection you're welcome to ask for help. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem **after upgrade from 16.10** and tried the solution mentioned here (edit Networkmanager.conf) and many others. None did help. But then I just **deleted the wifi networks and connected again** and everything worked! Eg this was not a problem of network manager itself, but the connections did not work (visually all setting were the same, so I have no idea what caused it).

Answer (score 6):

Miraculously, a user from omgubuntu.co.uk had written a comment in one of their articles announcing the release of 17.04 that fixed this issue. The comment is as follows:

> ## wifi and networkmanager
>
> The new NetworkManager release 1.4.0 adds new features to change the
>   current MAC address of your Ethernet or Wi-Fi card (spoofing/cloning).
>   As a debian "sid" user i understand that being on bleeding edge,
>   sometimes new features and configs can be Incompatible with my machine
>   hardware!!! Now being a ubuntu user i can see that ubuntu is losing
>   his "user friendly" name and no more care for desktop users! This was
>   an unacceptable default config on Ubuntu's best days! Ubuntu haters
>   and criticists must be happy now!
>
> ## fix it
>
> edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file
>
> And add:
>
> ```
> [device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
> ```
>
> Restart the networkmanager service and use your wireless connection
>   :)"

I found that applying his fix by opening a Terminal and typing "sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf", adding the text he described, then rebooting my machine fixed the issue.

That being said, this default behavior is still a major bug and breaks functionality of wi-fi hardware for users, and definitely needs to be looked at. Thanks for your time!

Comment: And the winner is the leader of the resistance Mr. @johnconnorfx himself.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes this will fix the issue. But before doing these steps delete previously created wifi connections. Otherwise this won't fix the problem. Because for me once I deleted it only get it working.