# Connected to WiFi, but I have no internet

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have a problem, suddenly on my Ubuntu 17.04 (before in Ubuntu 16.10 I had the same problem) I lost Internet, but WiFi connected. I already try to connect the internet wire, and problem totally the same. Could anybody help me, please? P.S. after restarting it works, but if turn off, then wait a bit, then turn on, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you run `ping 8.8.8.8` from a terminal and update the post with your results?

Comment: It's still pinging. How much will it take? It have done about 1535 pings

Comment: Try rebooting you modem/router

Comment: Rebooting cannot help me. But I found problem inside router, with DHCP. So, I resetting​ router helped me

Comment: After next reboot, I again met that problem

Comment: Replace the router.

Comment: @CelticWarrior it isn't good solution) I just tested, on second OS Windows, I have internet, and I don't have that problem. And I have that problem on both laptops with Ubuntu

Comment: And yet you claim you have the same problem with Ethernet (LAN cable)? Please confirm.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yes

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried the following solution a few hours ago and the problem didn't occur anymore. I didn't restart the notebook yet, so I'm not sure if it is a persistent solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/147496

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I will try. I will tell you about results!

Comment: Sorry, but after waking from suspend, I got the same damn issue again :( Searching further on the internet I got the following bug report on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1683094 It seems it is related to systemd. Please vote for it, so that it will be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Oh..ok, I will wait, till they will close the issue :(