# Wifi shows connected but no internet

Tags: wireless, 17.04

Upgraded to ubuntu 17.04
Any advice for trouble shooting?

Update:
When I restart the router wifi works

Comment: I suspect DNS, try to "ping 8.8.8.8" (Google DNS) if this works you have conectivity, then try to "nslookup amazon.com" if the nslookup fails you are likely to have a DNS problem, take a look in the Systemlog.

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried the following solution a few hours ago and the problem didn't occur anymore. I didn't restart the notebook yet, so I'm not sure if it is a persistent solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/147496