# Upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04, cannot connect to libraries

Tags: 16.04, apt, 17.04

I was upgrading my system (on laptop) from 16.04 to 17.04. To do so I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 to 17.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. It all went fine, until I tried opening my browsers (firefox and chrome). Then I performed a `sudo apt-get update` and got the following. How do I fix this?

```
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease   Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
0% [Working]
 Err:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease   Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Working]
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease   Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
0% [Working]
Err:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease   Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
0% [Working]
Err:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease   Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
$ exit
exit 
Script done on Sat 15 Apr 2017 03:24:29 PM ADT
```

edit: This question has not been answered, and none of the other answered questions have solved this.

(edit: honestly, I have given up and downgraded back to 16.04)

Comment: Format the output as code (the **`{}`** button in the editor or Ctrl+K) and you will be allowed to have as many URLs in it as you want.

Comment: @bytecommander done.

Comment: Can you ping the mentioned domains, like `ping -c4 ca.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Output: "ping: ca.archive.ubuntu.com: Name or service not known", I can't ping other sites like google.com either @Byte

Comment: Just to confirm that you have a DNS problem, in `terminal` type `host www.google.com` and `host 8.8.8.8`. The first one should fail, the second one should work. Then do `ps auxc | grep dns`. Tell us what happened.

Comment: Input: "host www.google.com" Output: list of "www.google.com has address 142.166.12.(some number)" (I got that line 8 times). Input: "host 8.8.8.8" Output: "8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com."  The last one has no output.

Comment: Those are the correct answers for the host commands... so it looks like DNS is working. Open `Software & Updates`, Ubuntu Software tab, and change the server to `Server for the United States` and see if that helps? Are you in Canada?

Comment: Sorry for the tardy response, I had a meeting. I switched over to "us.archive..." but I get the same error as I did before. @heynnema edit: indeed I am in canada.

Comment: Your problem sounds so much like a DNS problem, yet the host commands gave us the correct answers. They've changed the way DNS works in 17.04, and we're all still trying to figure how it works now. I don't have any more ideas for you at this time. If I come up with something... I'll be back. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema see below

Comment: @ByteCommander see below

Comment: I do not see any mention of the user using wifi and the duplicate linked to is for wifi only,  it is concerning the changes in how mac addresses are handled in network manager and the DNS issue can effect both wired and wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I should apologise to everyone. I have come to believe that the issues I encountered were local (mainly the wifi card) and not an issue with 17.04 itself.

How do I know? I only just opened the laptop again and attempted to view websites. It worked. I performed an update and it worked. I used the terminal to ping obscure sites and it worked. The issue somehow resolved itself.

Thank you for everyone who tried to help, I will definitely get my laptop checked.

EDIT: I WAS WRONG!!!!!!!! It now says I have lost the connection again and get the same error. I spoke with a classmate and he says it's because of randomising MAC addresses. The configuration file that we suspect responsible is /etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad it's working for you now. +1

Comment: @heynnema see edit above

Comment: Do you have the info to edit that file, or do you need my help?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/905263/wifi-unable-to-connect-after-upgrade-to-17-04 for the fix.

Comment: I followed the instructions. It worked at first. But when I booted it on the second try it does not work. @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

Solved it the editing issue.

Here is how:

- I followed the other thread that had the same problem as me here: [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)

HOWEVER, there is one very important difference. Using gedit to edit the config file may give you the following terminal output (Or something very similar):

```
** (gedit:2540): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported** 

** (gedit:2540): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported**
```

To attack this, I found a bug report (here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1575484) which basically says that **GUI level editors being used for sudo level editing is generally a BAD IDEA**. So instead I used VIM via the terminal and edited the config file that way. That is the only way my chnages to config file were registered, even though opening the file implied otherwise.

Good luck to anyone else who has this issue, hope it helps.

Comment: @heynnema . Finally and officially fixed.

Comment: Some portion of your answer(s) seems like an update to the original question. and that information should be [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/905222/edit) in the original question instead of  writing answers. [Answering a question using an answer from another post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16031/answering-a-question-using-an-answer-from-another-post), this might also help you :)