# Wifi unable to connect after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 17.04

I upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and although wifi is detected but it is unable to connect.

I tried to remove and reinstall drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install linux-generic bcmwl-kernel-source
```

But still it doesn't work.
WiFi adaptor: TP-Link WDN 4200

lsusb result:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0458:003a KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)
NetScroll+ Mini Traveler / Genius NetScroll 120
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:0736 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:3573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3573 Wireless Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
```

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: TP-Link WDN4200 has a Realtek chipset and what you purged/installed relates to Broadcom chipsets only. The first thing you need to understand is that solutions are hardware specific.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` And also: `lsmod | grep rtl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known bug in Network Manager in Ubuntu 17.04. Let's amend one file and try to fix it. Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Add lines:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=0
```

Save and close file then reboot. Now are you able to connect?

Comment: Upvoted because it worked but can you provide a link to the bug ?

Comment: Sure. Please check here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513