# after installing 17.04 the zyxel usb wifi no longer works

Tags: wireless, usb

i installed 16.10, all worked fine. after i updated to 17.04 ubuntu no longer was able to connect to the zyxel usb NWD2105.
Any hints what to do or where to get the drivers needed?

Comment: This may be helpful:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/905263/wifi-unable-to-connect-after-upgrade-to-17-04/905487#905487

Comment: thx ur link is helpful. not sure if i will do or wait until this bug is fixed. anyway don't understand why they broke the code...

Comment: If you want your wireless to work, I'd certainly try it. It is only two lines added to the file and a reboot.

Comment: already went back to 16.10. it is a shame that something working is broken in a new release. this is a question of QA regression testing, which seems to be not sufficient.