# Wifi issue with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and my laptop connects to home wifi but acts as if the network is not working, no website would load. It's not the browser, none of the apps work. A dozen reboots of laptop and router did nothing. Other laptops (win7), phones and tv use this network without issues. All was fine this morning but then the home wifi just stopped working on ubuntu (after waking it from sleep). For a few minutes it worked fine connected to the extender of that home wifi but then stopped that too. 
Ubuntu connects and uses my mobile hotspot without issues, so far.
Any ideas?
None of the fixes in previously asked similar questions worked for me so I was told in another thread to ask my own question.

Comment: try forgetting the network than reconnecting?

Comment: try this may be it will work : sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: I tried both of those several times before posting the question here, didn't work.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019

Comment: Jay, I tried that before posting my question and it didn't work, or it worked until next reboot / wake-up. After that, going through the steps again didn't work. But DNS change suggested below  is working for now.

Comment: The DNS change that you accepted below is the same what multiple answers to the linked question suggest. I'm voting to keep this question closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this: (solved my problem with DNS)

1. Right click on Wi-Fi icon at the top-right corner of the screen
2. go to "Edit Connections..."
3. Mark your wifi network
4. click "Edit" button
5. Open "IPv4 Settings" tab
6. Choose method: "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"
7. Copy&Paste `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` to "DNS servers"
8. Save
9. Reboot PC

Comment: This worked (editing connection)! Hopefully it sticks because the other fixes I tried only worked until the next reboot or wake up. Thanks!

Comment: This is bug report that concerns many users of 17.04. Note that the problem affects both wifi & ethernet, some of the other reports are wifi or usb wifi only. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1654918

Comment: I believe that you can mark this as solution to your problem with that green sign.

Comment: Tried this and it hasn't work. I'm I missing something. What is potentially causing this issue?

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. I already do this and I still experience random dropouts especially at critical times. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link of the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513).

And here is what you should try:

Open a terminal and type or paste this and run it:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Then edit the file and add these lines to the bottom of the file:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Save the file and run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I believe this issue that you give the fix for prevents you from connecting to wifi at all.  The OP says he can connect to wifi, but not the internet.  Ergo, DNS problem.

Comment: If that is the case, the OP should try running this command in a terminal:         sudo killall dnsmasq

Comment: On reboot, the wifi doesn't even connect anymore, when I removed the inserted line in `NetworkManager.conf`and reboot I get a wifi connection but no internet.

Comment: Even if this didn't answer OP's question, it fixed an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

**AIP (Answer in Progress)**

Wild guess, have you tried changing your DNS?

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

change `nameserver 127.0.0.53` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, save & close.

Comment: No no no. You don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf. It even says so RIGHT IN THE FILE.

Comment: because it will get rewritten on the next boot up, but we only need to see if this works

Comment: To get clarification from the OP, it's customary to drop a comment which you have the [reputation to do](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) (so far)

Comment: THIS HAS FINALLY solved my issue in my Starbucks coffee wifi shop .... how to make it permanent?