# lubuntu firefox and chromium can't connect to internet but tor-browser can

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, firefox, chromium

I can see websites with tor-browser but Firefox and chromium can't load any page.
when I disconnect from WiFi and connect again only half of one page loads but after a second it stops loading pages !

Comment: I use Lubuntu 17.04 and every thing is updated. my Lubuntu browsers were working good with another WiFi (in my home) but when I came to my office this problem appeared !

Comment: I guess this happens because of IPv6 enabled. To test, reboot your system and in GRUB page, press e to edit and find `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line and add `ipv6.disable=1` after splash. boot and see if your problem is solved or not.

Comment: i couldn't find  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" but i disabled IPv6 of my wifi connection and reboot but still have the problem

Comment: Can you confirm that IPv6 is still disabled after boot?

Comment: I used this and it solved the problem:
[wifi issue with ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/905432/681122)