# Wifi is not working in acer one 14 L1410 MODEL

Tags: 16.04, drivers, suspend, acer

3 days ago I purchased an Acer One 14 L1410 laptop which comes with Realtek rtl8xxxu card, I have installed ubuntu. Everything is going fine but WiFi is not working well. I have searched everywhere but nothing solved my issue. My laptop have a function key for WiFi on and off. when I restart I have to first press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and again press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> then WiFi connects. But after suspend its again not showing any connection.i have updated my pc and now connection is permanentaly closed

```
rfkill list all
0: hci:Bluetooth
     soft blocked:no
     hard blocked:no
1: Phy0:Wireless lan 
     soft blocked:no
     hard blocked:no

lsmod | grep 8xxx
rtl8xxxu  12786 0
mac721    15568 1  rtl8xxxu

lshw | grep 8xxx
configuration: driver=rtl8xxxu  driverversion=4.8.0-36-generic firmware=N/A  
 link=no multicast=YES wireless=IEEE 802.11

iwconfig
lo   no wireless extensio

lsusb
Bus  002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003  Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus  001 Device 003: ID 5986:065e  Acer , Inc
Bus  001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b720  Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus  001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002  Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lsmod | grep rtl
 rtl8xxxu  126976    0
 mac80211  761856    1  rtl8xxxu
 btrtl     16384     1  btusb
 bluetooth 557056    33 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb

 dmesg | grep rtl 


[   13.791360] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723

[   13.791366] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   13.958444] usb 1-4: rtl8723bu_parse_efuse: dumping efuse (0x200 bytes):
[   13.958560] usb 1-4: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723bu_nic.bin
[   14.872471] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8xxxu

 dmesg | grep wlx
[   15.105720] rtl8xxxu 1-4:1.2 wlx38a28c721f20: renamed from wlan0
[   15.105720] rtl8xxxu 1-4:1.2 wlx38a28c721f20: renamed from wlan0
[   24.306380] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready
[   24.324653] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready

[   24.532712] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready

[ 1502.527895] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1502.530422] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1502.734039] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1502.938059] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1503.142122] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1504.348097] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1504.356574] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1504.557930] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1504.761743] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1504.966010] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1512.688944] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1512.694231] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1512.897715] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1513.101736] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1513.305858] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1515.456885] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1515.465607] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1515.669717] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1515.873765] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1516.077431] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1527.977833] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready

[ 1528.255462] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1528.260375] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1528.461203] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1528.665292] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1528.868958] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1546.032087] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1546.036677] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1546.240766] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1546.444619] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1546.648668] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1552.978952] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready

[ 1562.206598] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1562.209287] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1562.412164] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1562.615782] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1562.819863] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1577.977091] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready

[ 1587.217967] wlx38a28c721f20: authenticate with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4

[ 1587.229397] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 1/3)

[ 1587.431242] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 2/3)

[ 1587.635244] wlx38a28c721f20: send auth to 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 (try 3/3)

[ 1587.839278] wlx38a28c721f20: authentication with 98:de:d0:27:46:f4 timed out

[ 1602.975590] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx38a28c721f20: link is not ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the *exact* result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: the result of rfkill list all is everything is unblocked

Comment: When you first boot up? After you press Fn+F3 twice? After suspend? Is acer-wireless shown at all times? Any other *-wireless? phy0?  It is very difficult to guess a solution without details.

Comment: yes every time when bootup connection fails...i have to press twice FN+F3 to get a connection.after suspend the wifi disconnects and no network showed at all time

Comment: So you are confirming that `rfkill list all` shows `acer-wireless` and phy0 in all such cases and there are no blocks ever. Correct?

Comment: yes...hey sir can you check himself .i am very new to linux i can give you my anydesk id..

Comment: No, thanks. Next, let's check to see if the wireless driver is loaded at boot when it's not working. Find out with: `lsmod | grep 8723` Again, on a fresh boot when the wireless is *not* working.

Comment: this command doesn't give any response..

Comment: i have done some reseach and found my driver is "rtl8xxxu"..and lsmod | grep 8xxx gives me output like this---  rtl8xxxu      126976 0 and mac80211   761856 1  rtlxxxu

Comment: Please post the output of `lsusb` to your question

Comment: May we see: `lsmod | grep rtl` and also: `dmesg | grep rtl` I actually suspect that the *acer-wmi* is not the problem.

Comment: wait i am updating both in question

Comment: You had a wireless interface,  wlx38a28c721f20 but, according to iwconfig, it went away. Let's try to find out why: `dmesg | grep wlx`

Comment: i have updated the information

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

The final result will look like this

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor and then run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: no there is no...i have to press the Fn + F4 twice to work again..

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart dont work for me...and if i hit fn+f4 twice then it connects automatically

Comment: Not Fn+F3 as before?? I'm confused.

Comment: sorrry its a mistakeit is f4,,my pc has a function key to enable and disable the wifi by default its always on even at startup but wifi doesnt connect but if i disable the wifi using Fn + F4 and enable again using Fn+F4 ,,,wifi gets connected

Comment: When you boot and it does *not* work, before you press anything, is the driver loaded? `lsmod | grep rtl` Or does it load after the two presses?

Comment: yes driver is loaded all the time..

Comment: If you do: `sudo rfkill block all && sleep1 && sudo rfkil unblock all` Does it start without pressing any button? I may have an ugly hack.

Comment: no it shows device is not ready...but again applying Fn+F4 twice...it connects

Comment: Regrettably, I see nothing in your readings that is wrong and therefore fixable. I am very sorry that I have no other ideas or suggestions.

Comment: what does it mean lo--no wireless extension   when we check in iwconfig....also nmcli d shows that lo is not managed by network manager

Comment: lo - no wireless extensions means that it, the loopback interface, is not a wireless interface. That is why it is not managed by NM; it does not connect outside the computer itself.

Comment: in (lshw | grep 8xxx)  firmware=N/A.....DOES IT MAKE SENSE IN ERROR  ??

Comment: Your dmesg above clearly shows that firmware was loaded.

Comment: you mean..it is not a error   ??..HOW CAN I FIND A ERROR ,I MEAN WHAT IS WRONG WITH MY PC ?...IS THERE ANY LOG COMMAND  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem as this. I have replaced the drivers with r8168-dkms_8.044.02-2_all.deb after which at least the cable ethernet works properly, but the wi-fi deactivates at every shut-down and has to be physically turned off and on again before it will connect.

Edit: After much research, I found the answer. The key was in lsusb: ID 0bda:b720. The 'b720' refers to either the rtl8723au or bu chipset.

ref: sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7

This machine uses the rtl8723bu chip and there is a driver by lwfinger here:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu

and a dkms version by James Buren can be found here:

https://launchpad.net/~ryu0/+archive/ubuntu/realtek-modules

Comment: have you tried this.......https://askubuntu.com/questions/905283/wifi-issue-with-ubuntu-17-04

Comment: Thanks Ankit, but see above.

Comment: Hey bro u628898 please help.. how u have fixed it.. i am stuck again after clean install.. please tell me how to install this driver

Comment: please tell me step by step...

Comment: Hey Ankit, this page gives you pretty much step by step info: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7. FWIW I still haven't got the bluetooth working properly, but I've run out of steam!

Comment: there are two things to follow.. 1 is given in this link which u hv send me and

Comment: 2-the steps mentioned in github driver page... which method should i follow?.. 1 or 2