# Why did I lose my wifi connections after upgrading to 17.10?

Tags: wireless, upgrade, 17.10

I just upgraded to 17.10 and now cannot use the wifi on my laptop. I tried some of the suffested fixes for similar bugs in the last few upgrades, but with no luck. Ideas?

Things I've tried :

https://askubuntu.com/a/905432/751621
[Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/q/902992/751621)

I should add that my Ubuntu laptop is the only device in the house which can't connect, and that I've also tried "forgetting" the network and joining again.

Comment: Not sure we can help with the provided info. You should update the question with details https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: I cannot be the only person who has lost connectivity again after a so-called "upgrade." I have no connectivity via wired connection either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to reset the bios to factory defaults to regain wifi. 
You can use a camera to record what you have before resetting. 
My best guess was it had something to do with power rather than networking itself. 
Same hardware, same wifi same everything just an updated Ubuntu. 
If you figure out what fixes your problem please report back.

Answer (score 0):

I also lost Wi-Fi. I tried to turn on and off flight modus FN+F8 (?) and then reboot Ubuntu. When I started again it worked.