# Ubuntu 17.04 wifi connected but not working

Tags: wireless, 17.04

I recently upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and right after upgrade wifi failed.
I followed these instructions [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019?newreg=e08dbc3a40f84b54be034176b8fa0129) but it didn t work for me.

I got this error

```
** (gedit:6996): Warning **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata: :gedit-spell-language not supported
** (gedit:6996): Warning **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata: :gedit-encoding not supported
```

I am working on a Dell Latitude D630

Comment: I'm expiriencing this on dell too. Is it possible that *some* websites are accessible though? For me, I can go on askubuntu.com but not on youtube or gmail.