# Can't connect to Wi-Fi with Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless

I've changed my Linux distribution from Opensuse 13.2 to Ubuntu 17.04. I could connect to my Wi-Fi with my old distribution but I can't do it with Ubuntu even though the WiFi icon shows me my house network. I've tried to fix it with the instructions in this link [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)
But it doesn't work.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: DId you try `sudo service network-manager restart` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, found no solution. What I eventually did was to uninstall networkmanager and replace it with [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/).

```
sudo apt-get install wicd 

sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

It worked instantly and the taskbar applet worked flawless after a restart.