# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS - connected to wireless but unable to access internet

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm a novice in linux and am trying to set up a homelab to learn. I have recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 and had issues in connecting the wireless initially. I updated the kernel and was then able to connect to the wireless. But I'm unable to connect to the internet.

I tried couple of suggestions I found here ( changing the network conf file ) but to no avail.

output from nmcli -device command to show that the wireless is connected

[output from command /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ8op.png)

have uploaded the output on the below link
https://imgur.com/a/TFvXg

Comment: Could you provide us with a the command `ifconfig` and also give us your interfaces file located in /etc/network/

Comment: Here's the output from ifconfig . Could you please advise me how to obtain the files located in /etc/network. Sorry, i'm a beginner and kindly bear with my naive questions :)

Comment: This is going to sound really dumb. I am unable to copy the output since there's a restriction . I don't see an option to upload an image or file here .can't see what I am missing

Comment: A picture from your phone is good enough for me upload it to imgur or somthing like that and post the link here :)

Comment: here's the link to the ifconfig output https://imgur.com/a/TFvXg

Comment: I have also posted the output from /etc/network as well

Comment: I tried upgrading to version 17.04 to check if the issue will be resolved. But with 17.04 the wireless wasn't even detected. After trying several options, i stumbled upon this option listed here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/906633/cant-connect-to-wi-fi-with-ubuntu-17-04?rq=1
I uninstalled network manager and installed wicm. It works fine now!