# Ubuntu 17.04 connected to wifi but can't browse internet

Tags: wireless, internet, 17.04

I have connected to my wifi correctly but I cannot seem to search for anything as it just says "Server Not Found". Other computers on the same network can still search the internet though.

This has been flagged as a duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)
However the solution used I have already attempted and it has failed to reconcile my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing)

Comment: See also [Ubuntu 17.04 systemd-resolved DNS lookups randomly fail](//superuser.com/q/1153203) but I found the same problem was fixed for me by `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` - bug seems fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue here.

I resolved it by adding a DNS server address for the connection.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant, however I am not very well versed in what looks like German? How would I go about this?

Comment: It's dutch. You click on the wifi symbol, then edit connections. Then go to ipv4 settings and type in the DNS adres of your ISP

Comment: Okay I'll give it a go. Sorry for any offence

Comment: No problem ,hope it works for you. P.s. you can use google's DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 too

Comment: Another note if you are trying to connect to a public Wifi: I had this issue that when I was trying to Sign in (in this case to Starbucks Wifi), I would get a DNS lookup error for secure.datavalet.io, so I had to redirect it to my default gateway IP address, so I add it to my /etc/host.

Answer (score 11):

#### This was Originally posted by [Mike_IronFist](https://askubuntu.com/users/68016/mike-ironfist) over [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/665251)

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Your final results should look something like this:
[image: Configuration file to allow USB Wifi to work in Ubuntu 17.04]

Then just save and close the file and run:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And wifi should work again!

---

(if above steps doesn't help)

you should also know that Ubuntu 17.04 can not resolve DNS servers with DNSSEC support as of 2017-04-18.  Disable DNSSEC with this daemon:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d
printf "[Resolve]\nDNSSEC=no\n" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/no-dnssec.conf
```

Reconfigure resolvconf if needed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
# Say yes to "prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?"
```

And reboot.

Comment: I have already tried this and it has not changed anything. I had already used this solution for an earlier issue

Comment: @BlueDabbaDee then please include that in the question next time ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I will

Comment: I am facing the opposite problem. After a update, the computer is getting connected to ethernet but internet browsing not working. On the same computer (16.04 LTS) the wifi is working flawlessly for everything. I am still searching for an answer here before posting a question.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the second part about the resolvconf solved my problem. However, it seems all that was needed was to reconfigure resolvconf. Presence or absense of the new .conf file did not have any effect..