# Cannot connect to WiFi available networks in 17.04

Tags: wireless

when I select the Wi-Fi network, after trying connect for sometime, I get a "Disconnected - cannot connect to the network" response.

I tried connecting to Wi-Fi on terminal could not find WLAN0. although the available networks show the name properly.

can connect to a mobile network though.
any help/response is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you connect to mobile hotspot? or via USB tethering?

Comment: i cannot to a mobile broadband (like MTS). but not a WiFi

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/907771/665251 try if this works for you

Comment: thanks @SumeetDeshmukh. it worked. plus there was one tiny variation. I had to take out the USB adapter and connect it back again. thanks again for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019) was actually the solution. 
It worked with a twist for me. I had to remove and insert the USB adapter to connect. (Yep! that was silly)

Thanks [Sumeet Deshmukh](https://askubuntu.com/users/665251/sumeet-deshmukh) for the help.