# Wireless adapter stopped working after installing 17.04

Tags: wireless

I've decided to upgrade a computer to Ubuntu 17.04. It previously had 14.04 on it and was working okay, but on this new installation the wireless usb adapter is working strangely.

Here's what happens, the adapter is recognized and I can see wireless networks in the network indicator menu. When I select the ssid for my home wireless network (wireless N only, WPA2) I am prompted for the password to my wireless network. After I provide the password, the network indicator start a connecting. After approximately 15 seconds I get a notification that my wireless connection is disconnected from the network and I am back where I started.

I have other wireless devices that can connect to the my network before I installed 17.04.

The wireless adapter is an Asus USB-N53.

What should I try next to resolve this issue where I can't connect to my network?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/907771/665251 see if this works

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed the problem by removing the gnome networking manager and installing wicd as described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD