# wifi unstable ubuntu 17

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 17.04

wifi connects but no login, then disconnects?
tried:

```
sudo systemctl restart networkmanager.service    no good
sudo nano service dnsmasq stop, sudo nano service network-manager restart
```

nope

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#DNSSEC=allow=downgrade     to
DNSSEC=off   and the ^X will not save the change
settings/network/wired/options
```

and close the enp4s0 option nothing.did an edit connection to `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4`  no help. or please show me where to find the answer I an looking for.

tried a few more network manager restart still nothing.

I run a dual boot Ubuntu 17.o4 and windows 10, very new to Ubuntu and Wi-Fi
a lot of the answers that people give I have no idea what they do or mean, so I type it in word for word, and some get typed in the wrong place. (my bad, do not understand the system yet).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/907763/ubuntu-17-04-connected-to-wifi-but-cant-browse-internet try these two answers and comeback with results

Answer (score 0):

Get the name of your wifi driver by running

```
lspci | grep Wireless
```

then search for the drivers online, and install them. As you did not provide the driver name, I can’t help any further. However, to build the drivers(if needed), you do:

```
cd (folder that contains the drivers)
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

then your WiFi should be more stable.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add the following lines to that file

```
[device]

wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

To save the changes press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

this should work in your case