# Can't connect to select wi-fi networks in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I just upgraded from 16 to 17.10 and now when I try to connect to public starbucks wi-fi it does not work. Works fine for all other wi-fi networks.

As soon as I select it from the list of wi-fi networks it gives me the pop up and says it connected, but then changes to an error page saying:

```
'Error resolving “secure.datavalet.io”: Name or service not known'.
```

Any attempt to load a web page gives this result:
    Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at secure.datavalet.io.
If that address is correct, here are three other things you can try:

```
Try again later.
Check your network connection.
If you are connected but behind a firewall, check that Firefox has permission to access the Web.
```

I have tried [this solution already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019) and no results.

Edit: The network works just fine on my phone. And it worked fine in the past before I updated to 17.10. So I don't believe it's a problem with the server.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [Formatting Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: I am facing the same issue...very weird...

Comment: Someone mentioned here, https://askubuntu.com/questions/907763/ubuntu-17-04-connected-to-wifi-but-cant-browse-internet that he installed Linux Mint and the connection is now working for him. I am facing the same issue as you are with Gnome 2.62 but maybe you can try connecting through the Mint session and see if it works (I haven't tried yet) ? The installation should be straightforward: https://www.howtogeek.com/103691/install-linux-mints-new-cinnamon-desktop-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @user283411 this question would be a good place to expand your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907763/ubuntu-17-04-connected-to-wifi-but-cant-browse-internet#comment1573719_907774) into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 17.10 in a Starbucks in Montreal. I was able to fix it by removing the manual configuration of my wireless NIC.

In gnome-shell:

Settings > Network > Gear icon on your wireless NIC > IPv4 tab > Change to Automatic (DHCP)

You will probably need to do the same for IPv6

Settings > Network > Gear icon on your wireless NIC > IPv6 tab > Change to Automatic, (DHCP) only