# WiFi connected but no Internet lubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet

Internet access stopped suddenly on two separate lubuntu laptops, one running 16.04 and another 17.10. They still show connected to WiFi. However I am able to access the Internet on other devices.

I haven't changed any network/router configurations so I don't know how both the computers stopped connecting within the space of a couple of days. It seems to be a DNS issue but the solution suggested in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907763/ubuntu-17-04-connected-to-wifi-but-cant-browse-internet!) doesn't seem to help.

Edit : ping 8.8.8.8 returns "connect: Invalid argument". 
ifconfig returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6c0i.jpg)

Edit 2: If it helps, I get an err_address_unreachable error when trying to connect. 
Rebooting and running ifconfig again, I get the following:

```
enp5s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:11:32:9d:69:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1129  bytes 191372 (191.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1129  bytes 191372 (191.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2640:952e:2a5f:296d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:a4:de:a9:49:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 142  bytes 33255 (33.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 507  bytes 54531 (54.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edit 3: ping 8.8.8.8 now results in: 
`27 packets transmitted, 0 received, +19 errors, 100% packet loss, time 26597ms pipe 4`

Edit 4: the 16.04 had the mac address bug and it is now resolved. I was thrown off track - these are separate issues. Should I make a separate post?

Comment: Why do you think that "it seems to be a dns issue". It could be a general network problem of your provider. Can you try with running `ping 8.8.8.8` (Google DNS Server) and add the output to the question. And please add the outputof `ifconfig` to the question.

Comment: I would only open another thread if there is a separate issue at this point. Please see my update for additional steps to help diagnose.

Comment: I was able to find a solution - I've added it as a separate answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounters the same issue, I was able to find a solution - it involved downloading a couple of packages. See [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387011) thread.

Comment: Glad to see you got there.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit difficult to see by that image, but it appears you aren't allocated an IPv4 address. If your router is handling DHCP, try rebooting the router then reboot your problematic devices.

Then provide the `ifconfig` outputs for any wifi adapters once more.

---

Update #1

With the confirmed allocated IP...
[I understand you went right to trying to ping a DNS server 8.8.8.8]

Ping your gateway router. You can confirm the ip with `ip r`.
Likely to be `192.168.1.1` based on your subnet.

If that succeeds, although I am not sure if it is installed by default,
give 
`mtr 8.8.8.8` a try and revert with findings.

Comment: I rebooted again but no luck. I've added the ifconfig output.

Comment: mtr 8.8.8.8 returns no values(I assume it should) :    `eys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                       Packets               Pings
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev`