# After cancelled upgrade mouse stops working

Tags: upgrade, network-manager, 16.10, do-release-upgrade, mouse-pointer

I run Ubuntu 16.10.
I decided to upgrade to 17.04 today, so I opened a terminal and typed `sudo do-release-upgrade`. I saw that Budgie (a desktop) was going to be removed. Since I was using Budgie at the time, I cancelled the upgrade. Then, I logged out of Budgie. Instead of selecting Unity, I accidentally chose Unity 8, which has a bug with logouts. So, I pressed ctrl-alt-f1, signed in, and typed `sudo reboot`. Then, at the login screen, the mouse, touchpad, and touchscreen would not work.

I tried running the upgrade again in the terminal, but the computer would not connect to the wifi. After some time using `nmcli`, I figured out that the computer was "connected" to the network and had "full internet access" even though it would not get any webpages. I can't connect to Ethernet because my laptop doesn't have an Ethernet port.

Is there any way I could get the mouse to work or connect to the network?

Comment: Try this fix here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019

Comment: I just tried that, it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: I just bought a USB Ethernet adapter. I can't get it to work, but others have. Any suggestions?