# Unable to connect the internet with Ralink RT2870 USB ABGN WLAN Card

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager, ralink

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 (gnome) but for some reason, I am not able to connect to the wifi network using Ralink 802.11n Wireless LAN Card (USB).

I am able to see all the available network but when I try to connect it keeps trying to connect for around 20 to 30 seconds and it automatically stops. I am able to connect to those networks from my laptop which also has Ubuntu 17.04 installed.

[Wifi Network List Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOwIW.png)

**lsusb output:**

```
kevin@My-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:259f Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard LKS02
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
kevin@My-PC:~$
```

**Here is the error log that I believe relates to the issue:**

```
wpa_supplicant
dbus: Failed to construct signal
dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none

Networkmanager
((devices/nm-device.c:970)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
```

I have tried restarting the PC, disabling and enabling the wifi and inserting the device into the different USB port.

**Update:**
The issue is only with Ubuntu 17.04. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked out of the box.

Comment: just tried this, and it worked! https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This... "feature" was introduced in 17.04, somewhere around kernel version 4.10, I believe.

Try if this works for you:

Edit */etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf*

And add lines:

```
[device]  
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then restart network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```