# No wired or wireless internet on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: wireless, internet, wired

**The problem**

No wired (USB tethering) or wireless (mobile hotspot) internet working on fresh Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 installation or Live USB. (I also tried out Kubuntu 17.04)

**What have I tried?**

1. I've tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/905019/665251) which fixed the random mac address problem in Ubuntu 17.04, this helped me to connect the wifi device but internet wasn't working
2. I've added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to DNS via settings app in Ubuntu, I also tried toggling "Automjatic DNS" to *Off*, this amkes no effect
3. Tried rebooting multiple times
4. Changed ports for USB wireless adopter

**Other strange things**

5. I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 in this same PC with those same devices attached multiple times before and it has worked for me, it's just not working from yesterday.
6. I've tried to dual boot with different operating system (Manjaro in this case) and internet works fine on Manjaro without any modifications.
7. `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping 8.8.4.4` works, but adding it to DNS doesn't fix the problem

**Information**

These outputs were taken in Live USB mode (I don't think that changes anything, but I might be wrong)

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network

       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: f0:4d:a2:f3:7a:15
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.6
       logical name: wlx20e617027069
       serial: 20:e6:17:02:70:69
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=4.10.0-19-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.229 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:0060 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

wireless script output

#### wireless info START

Report from: 28 Jan 2017 22:49 UTC +0000

Booted last: 28 Jan 2017 00:00 UTC +0000

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

kernel

Linux 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 6 17:04:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-gnome.seed, boot=casper, initrd=/casper/initrd.lz, quiet, splash, ---, maybe-ubiquity

desktop

sed: can't read /home/ubuntu-gnome/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

lspci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:04ed]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:0060 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18d1:4ee3 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (tether)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA card info

rfkill

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lsmod

mac80211              782336  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,mt7601u

interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ifconfig

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
3: wlx:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ' [IF2]> brd 
4: enp0s26u1u1:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.42.167/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic enp0s26u1u1
       valid_lft 3483sec preferred_lft 3483sec
    inet6 fe80::4ed0:c62f:e602:7612/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

iwconfig

enp0s26u1u1  no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

route

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s26u1u1 proto static metric 100 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s26u1u1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.167 metric 100

resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.53

network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root      4683     1  0 22:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s26u1u1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         LGE
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Nexus 5 CAF
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/net/enp0s26u1u1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s26u1u1
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ea3199d9-56bd-3455-87b1-bbd44236776b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ea3199d9-56bd-3455-87b1-bbd44236776b | Wired connection 2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.167/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.167
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1485647249
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = ubuntu-gnome
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::4ed0:c62f:e602:7612/64
IP6.GATEWAY:

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         MediaTek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11 n WLAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         mt7601u
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-19-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         ' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.6/2-1.6:1.0/net/wlx
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  *

NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[devices]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

NetworkManager profiles

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=' [IF2]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=AndroidAP
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

iw reg get

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

iwlist channels

enp0s26u1u1  no frequency information.

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlx  14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

iwlist scan

enp0s26u1u1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlx  No scan results

module infos

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6FCDB39CB1DCCA0C9A450B2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-19-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     0ADFC23D0B6BCD6916160E7
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

module parameters

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

/etc/modules

modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

rc.local

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

pm-utils

udev rules

dmesg

[   17.489780] mt7601u 2-1.6:1.0 wlx: renamed from wlan0
[   18.614680] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   18.750276] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   18.750440] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   18.753789] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx: link is not ready (repeated 4 times)
[  215.849586] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[  215.853570] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)
[  227.764864] wlx: authenticate with 
[  227.797473] wlx: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  227.799094] wlx: authenticated
[  227.800250] wlx: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  227.803500] wlx: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  227.848816] wlx: associated
[  227.848882] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx: link becomes ready
[  227.922288] wlx: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 
[  433.904035] wlx: deauthenticated from  (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  435.372459] wlx: authenticate with 
[  435.404495] wlx: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  435.607911] wlx: send auth to  (try 2/3)
[  435.839905] wlx: send auth to  (try 3/3)
[  436.043898] wlx: authentication with  timed out
[  442.091157] rndis_host 1-1.1:1.0 enp0s26u1u1: renamed from usb0
[  442.116011] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s26u1u1: link is not ready
[  449.008015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx: link is not ready

#### wireless info END