# ALFA AWUS036NH in Ubuntu 17.04 never completes connection

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, network-manager

This is my lsusb:

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter`

I've modprobe'd rt2800 several times and network-manager scans successfully and displays SSIDs but open or WPA connections never complete. The spinner works, the network seems connected and then drops.

dmesg:

`[ 1010.319366] wlx00c0ca58e95a: authenticate with 64:66:b3:56:AA:c8
[ 1010.353146] wlx00c0ca58e95a: send auth to 64:66:b3:56:AA:c8 (try 1/3)
[ 1010.558943] wlx00c0ca58e95a: send auth to 64:66:b3:56:AA:c8 (try 2/3)
[ 1010.560859] wlx00c0ca58e95a: authenticated`

How do I solve this ?

Comment: Please try this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing

Comment: @chili555 I have no words. Thanks a lot. But why does it work ?

Comment: It bypasses a small bug in Network Manager as of 17.04. Glad it's working!