# Can't connect to wireless network ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 17.04 and I can't connect to a wi-fi network, while other devices are OK.

There is no error message, it just hangs and disconnects.

output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list":

```
Subsystem: TP-LINK Technologies Co., Ltd. TG-3468 Gigabit PCI Express Network Adapter [7470:3468]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

usb dongle:

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8189 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187B Wireless 802.11g 54Mbps Network Adapter`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's done

Comment: It doesn't look like a full output. And please also add the `lsusb` output. Is it a laptop or a desktop? Are you using some USB dongle?

Comment: yes, it's a USB dongle. I added some info.

Comment: Please try this first:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing