# Wireless networks show up but will not connect (Panda Wirelass PAU06)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I recently installed ubuntu to replace windows after it acted up. I have used ubuntu before but this time my wireless adapter will not connect. I have a usb wifi adapter its a Panda Wireless PAU06 I dont know if that helps but I can connect to ethernet just fine its only the problem with wireless connections

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsb_release -a`

Comment: @chili555 I'm having the exact same problem. Here's the output of `lsb_release -a` from my installation.

alexdresko@linux1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 17.04
Release: 17.04
Codename: zesty

Comment: In 17.04, this is often the solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing