# Lubuntu 17.04 will not connect to WiFi (no error message displayed)

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, 17.04

I just installed Lubuntu 17.04. It did not recognise the WiFi card I had in the MB, so I took a TP-Link WN722N USB stick. The system immediately recognised the USB WiFi stick and offered networks to connect to. But at any attempt to connect, the system just gives up after a while without explanation. I do not have any special settings, just regular AES password protection. What can I do other than search for a different distribution?

Comment: Have you retried restarting the network-manager by `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: It depends on which revision of wn722n it is. Searching for a different distibution won't help.They all use the same kernel. You can search for solutions regaring your built-in wireless adapter and the dongle. You may need some drivers or settings.

Comment: As @Pilot6 was getting at, you may need to download and reinstall your specific wifi adapter drivers. If you do choose to do this, you can use `modprobe`.

Comment: Please try this first: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening

`sudo leafpad /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

added the line

`[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no`

then I restarted the service

`sudo service network-manager restart`

...and I got connected! The browser still has a problem connecting to the internet, but I guess that is a different issue. Thanks for the suggestions.