# Lubuntu connected to network, pings router, but cannot access internet

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet

After some problems [Lubuntu 17.04 will not connect to WiFi (no error message displayed)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939674/lubuntu-17-04-will-not-connect-to-wifi-no-error-message-displayed) I finally got connected, but I still have no access to the internet.

I got an IPv4 address 192.168.1.89

I can ping that address from other computers on the network.

The Lubuntu (latest version 17.04) computer in question can ping outside the network, for example pinging google on this address worked ok:

```
ping 216.58.201.110
```

But the browser still gives me SERVER NOT FOUND

Comment: Which version of Lubuntu are you using? Does other computers in the same network uses **PROXY** in order to surf the web?

Comment: The link you posted seems unrelated and it's old. All you have apparently is a DNS issue.

Comment: Question updated (wrong link corrrected). No, I do not use PROXY on the network.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat  /var/log/syslog | grep -i dns`

Comment: The result is a mile-long list, so I just pasted the last three results:     `Nov  4 15:40:54 oldtimer systemd-resolved[909]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN DS: signature-expired
Nov  4 15:40:54 oldtimer systemd-resolved[909]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN SOA: signature-expired
Nov  4 15:40:54 oldtimer systemd-resolved[909]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.ubuntu.com IN A: signature-expired`