# Upgrades to Lubuntu 16.04 when installing

Tags: networking, dual-boot, upgrade, lubuntu

I have ISO discs of both Lubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 to trial Ubuntu.
I found when booting from the 17.04 disc Lubuntu could see my internet connection but would not connect to it.
After many goes at trying different recommendation from the net to rectify the issue I downloaded 16.04 ISO and booted off the 16.04 disc I was able to  connect to the internet at first go.

One of the fixes I followed was this [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)
but when I did gksu was not installed and when I tried a fix for that it would not work either hence me switching to 16.04.

I am impressed with 16.04 and would like to use it as my default O/S.

My question is when I install 16.04 alongside XP (that is already installed and I have to keep to run a couple of programs) and I am asked if I want to load updates will 16.04 be upgraded to 17.04 leaving me now facing the no internet issue again?

Please keep any answers very simplistic and low key with no acronyms abbreviations etc if possible as I am totally new to Ubuntu this being my only contact with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asked to download/install updates for your system, you should not be upgraded to 17.04, unless you explicitly set it to upgrade your computer.

As for not being able to run gksu, instead of running `gksu gedit` as specified in that answer, try `sudo nano`.

I hope this helps!