# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi after upgrading from ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04. The upgrade was successful, but now I cannot connect to WiFi - I see the list of available netwroks, but when I try to connect it seems to be connecting for several seconds and then stops (the icon returns to "no connection" status). I get no error message apart from the regular "Disconnected - you are now offline" notification.

My WiFi card is "Killer E220x Gigabit".

Thanks

Comment: And your wireless card is ......

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry, I just added the card type (from the output of sudo lshw -C network). lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 yields no output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019). Sorry for the duplicate.