# Ubuntu 17.04 connects to WiFi but no Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 17.04

I have gone through a number of forums and looked at a number of solutions that have worked for others, but nothing seems to be working for me. This is what I have tried so far:

1. Changed `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManger.conf` as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing).
2. I have also executed `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`
3. I have also tried upgrading the driver of my wireless card (Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter)

However nothing seems to be working. Would appreciate if someone could help me here please.

Comment: Can you show the output of a `traceroute 8.8.8.8` please? This will show us the path that traffic is taking, and should show us where it's getting 'stuck'.