# How to rollback from 17.04 to 16.04?

Tags: 17.04, downgrade

I upgraded to 17.04 but having some issue with wifi, how can I downgrade to 16.04?

Comment: Have you managed to run a full `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`? That fixes at least one of the 17.04 image WiFi bugs. The other one is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing)

Comment: "having some issue with wifi: So fix that: find the chipset, google chipset for issues and solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot downgrade the ubuntu version. You'll have to reinstall 16.04. 
The only solution is to re-install Ubuntu 16.04 and erase 17.04, so that you have a clean installation.

Just backup your relevant files, and run the installation CD/DVD/USB.

Erase Ubuntu 17.04 and install 16.04.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation