# Unable to connect to specific wifi network

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, dell

This has been asked a few times already, but no solution that I've found has helped.  I've tried every solution that I feel comfortable using.

I have a Dell XPS Developer Edition with Ubuntu 16.04 and it connects to every wireless network I connect to, except my home wifi.  I've connected with no issue to tens of other networks via wireless, but I can't at home.

My home wifi has no problem connecting to other 16.04 laptops, including ones with the same wireless card (not sure if same driver).

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:dc:d2:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-93-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:135 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx9cebe851ff48
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:51:ff:48
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ncm driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC NCM ip=192.168.1.116 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I've seen lots of answers involving `modprobe` but I'm not familiar with that, and after doing a bit of research, it doesn't seem like something I want to do all willy nilly (after only seeing it on places in relation to other adapters on other OS').  If someone posted the same thing here, knowing what hardware I had, I'd give it a try.

---

**EDIT 1**

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command

Comment: Edit 1 added with the requested info.

Comment: I tried all the following solutions, but none worked for me except the one posted here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1277071/35310 I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the issue for this.

I'm not 100% sure why it worked since I didn't notice the same issue as the individual who asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019), but it worked for me.

Edit the `NetworkManager.conf` file

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and disable random MAC addressing by adding these lines to the bottom of the file:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then, save the file, and restart the network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I already had the lines at the bottom of the file, but restarting the network manager according to this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 20.04 ! Adding this options in the `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file solved the issue !

run

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 wd_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and reboot your laptop

Answer (score 1):

I received same problem. But when I opened my `NetworkManager.conf` file I saw that random mac addressing was already disabled.

It is not possible to say it could work for everyone, but I changed my  wi-fi name and password and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277071/630837) answer worked, that is, type "nm-connection-editor" in the terminal, and then choose the specific WiFi Band (2.4GHz or 5GHz), instead of leaving it as "automatic".