# Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to connect to specific / home WIFI / WLAN

Tags: 18.04, wireless

On our home network, I am unable to connect to the wifi in Ubuntu 18.04

How to debug & fix it?

So far I tried:

- Tripple check that the correct password is used (only numbers)
- Connection to other WIFI / WLAN networks is possible (so I assume it is not a general driver issue)
- Verfied the security method
  Router / Fritz!Box 6490 : `WPA2 (CCMP)`
  On the Ubuntu Laptop it says `WPA & WPA2 Personal`

System Info

- OS : Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- WIFI Hardware: Wireless 8265 / 8275
- WIFI Driver: driverversion=4.15.0-54-generic

Answer (score 0):

So I was about to try various different solutions....

Before I did begin I saved my config - since I did not understand the solutions completely - and time is precious .. so:

```
cd /etc/
sudo git init .
sudo git add .
sudo git commit -a -m 'initial commit before experiments'
```

I checked this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/970718/230083 but my config matches already the solution.

Next I used this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2363514

After the seps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrde
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

I did again a `git status` which showed only little changes:

```
modified:   fonts/conf.avail/64-language-selector-prefer.conf
modified:   fonts/conf.avail/69-language-selector-zh-hk.conf
modified:   ld.so.cache
```

Anyway I committet and tried connecting to the network again - and it worked !!

So I'm not sure how this got it fixed since I install updates whenever they appear in the tool "Software Update"