# Ubuntu 22.04 home wifi doesnt work sometimes

Tags: networking, wireless

I can't connect with my laptop to my home wifi *sometimes* but it does *always* connect to the acces point of my phone (which is connected to the wifi that doesn't work). I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960691/unable-to-connect-to-specific-wifi-network) but nothing.

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"..."  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 4A:FF:2A:8E:2B:CC   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
```

`sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: e4:a8:df:b6:3d:14
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.18.0-9.1-liquorix-amd64 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:49 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1604000-d1604fff memory:d1600000-d1603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 38:d5:7a:66:1f:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=5.18.0-9.1-liquorix-amd64 firmware=____010000-20220209150915 ip=192.168.234.219 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:71 memory:fc02000000-fc020fffff memory:fc02100000-fc02103fff memory:fc02104000-fc02104fff
```

These are the log lines (from using `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`) that appear when I try to connect to my home's wifi

```
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3332] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3333] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3334] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'netplan-wlo1-Wifi-Familia-Dumitru' has security, and secrets exist.  No new 
secrets needed.
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3335] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Wifi-Familia-Dumitru'
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3335] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3335] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3335] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3335] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3635] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.3925] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
jul 09 10:27:44 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355264.4333] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
jul 09 10:27:54 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355274.4631] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
jul 09 10:27:54 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355274.5777] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
jul 09 10:27:58 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355278.3423] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
jul 09 10:27:58 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355278.3516] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
jul 09 10:27:58 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355278.3999] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
jul 09 10:28:01 Valentin-LAPTOP NetworkManager[792]: <info>  [1657355281.2535] device (wlo1): disconnecting for new activation request.
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: I added the logs from that command.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs in MT7921 driver on 5.17 kernels. Partly fixed in 5.18, but even newest Ubuntu is still on 5.17