# wifi unavailable after updating 17.04

Tags: networking, wireless, updates

After installing the latest updates in ubuntu 17.04, my wifi is broken. In the network manager it just says 'Wifi unavailable'.

I have already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing), it doesn't help. It is as if my wifi card is powered off.

This is the output of some commands after the updates are installed:

```
uname -a
Linux athena 4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 20:20:37 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       ...

  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:24:7e:87:08:16
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-37-generic firmware=0.40 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7000000-f700ffff

sudo iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u3  no wireless extensions.
```

Is there anyway to go back to the state before last update? Any suggestions to try? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple more things and now wifi works again. Not sure what fixed it but I think it was this:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
sudo rm *
```

reboot