# Wireless connection issue with lubuntu

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, internet, dns

I have some weird issue with my wireless connections.
I can connect to a network, it works for a few seconds, and then there's a DNS error, I can't browse or anything, on chrome it says DNS Probe finished, no internet. But I still appear to be connected. If i reconnect to the same network, it works again for a few seconds and then go down again..
And some other time, I can't even connect to any network as it keeps asking for authentication.

bcmwl-kernel-source is installed.
I'm not used to linux so if you need any other piece of information, please ask.

It used to work fine as far as I remember, even thought i'm mostly connected to the internet with my cellphone by tethering.

I've try to look for answers on the internet, but to be honest I don't understand most of the proposed answers.
My lubuntu is not brand new, and I don't remember exactly what I've installed.

If someone has an idea to help me,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this link solved it !

[Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience!