# Wifi has stopped working unexpectedly on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04

I can connect to the network, but I can't access the internet.

I have tried several solutions, such as:

- Update the Kernel to the last one version.
- Set up a list of DNSs (como 8.8.8.8) in the wifi settings.
- [Set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing) the property wifi.scan-rand-mac-address to no (Actually, I was already working this way).

When I use a Live CD I get access. It stopped working after a while. As I did not use the wifi much regularly, I can't tell when it stopped working.

In the browser, I get `DNS_PROB_START` and then `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`.

*$ sudo lshw -class network*

```
      descrição: Interface sem fio
       produto: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nome lógico: wlp2s0
       versão: 31
       serial: 5c:c9:d3:8c:87:ff
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuração: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.18.0-041800-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5 ip=10.116.199.144 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:129 memória:a1000000-a11fffff
```

*$ lspci*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

*$ cat /etc/issue.net; uname -ar*

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Linux magneto 4.18.0-041800-generic #201808122131 SMP Sun Aug 12 21:33:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

*$ rfkill list all*

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

*$ dmesg*

```
[ 6062.371799] wlp2s0: disconnect from AP 0e:8d:cb:6f:63:bc for new auth to 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01
[ 6062.378165] wlp2s0: authenticate with 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01
[ 6062.413159] wlp2s0: send auth to 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01 (try 1/3)
[ 6062.413950] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 6062.421667] wlp2s0: associate with 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01 (try 1/3)
[ 6062.423506] wlp2s0: RX ReassocResp from 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=6)
[ 6062.427281] wlp2s0: associated
[ 6062.427355] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 0e:8d:cb:6f:71:01
[ 6062.427564] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x804c
[ 6062.427566] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[ 6062.427567] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[ 6062.427568] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x3b
[ 6062.427570] ath: Country alpha2 being used: BR
[ 6062.427571] ath: Regpair used: 0x3b
[ 6062.427573] ath: regdomain 0x804c dynamically updated by country element
[ 6941.786152] perf: interrupt took too long (3152 > 3130), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63250
```

*$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf*

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 jul 26 14:09 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/connman/resolv.conf
```

*$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8*

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

*$ cat /etc/resolv.conf*

```
# Generated by Connection Manager
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

*$ systemctl list-unit-files* [output here](https://gist.github.com/Michel-Alves/5c5a94142434dafdcfbc9481d392be41)

*$ route*

```
Tabela de Roteamento IP do Kernel
Destino         Roteador        MáscaraGen.    Opções Métrica Ref   Uso Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
10.116.199.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0
```

Thanks for listening

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the commands: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and also; `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`

Comment: We also need to see your route output and your systemctl list-unit-files output

Comment: You can erase most of that, it sounds like connman is running the same time as network manager or WPA, I'd have to see the unit files to be sure

Comment: Your resolve.conf output should be 127.0.0.1 with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4