# What should I put in the Network Manager configuration?

Tags: drivers, usb, network-manager

From this thread: [Ubuntu GNOME 17.04: wi-fi not working -- mac address keeps changing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902992/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-wi-fi-not-working-mac-address-keeps-changing/905019#905019)

I'm having some problems with wi-fi networks in my Linux.
I followed the thread above but when I put the code in terminal the Network Manager stops working.

There is a '[device]' in the code. But what device should I put? I have this list of my connected USBs:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04d9:a09f Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Wi-Fi device its the "Edimax Technology". I tried to put his name, ID, Device but no one worked.

Please, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are expected to put, simply, [device].

Comment: Basic questions... has your wireless ever worked? What are "some problems"? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `ifconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back to @heynnema